# How to delete a node of an octree c++ ( node was 0x4.)

Tags: c++, octree

I have an Octree and I have to delete a node searched by it's branch. The program can find the node but I'm struggled with delete it. When I create an object of my Octree and I create some nodes but I don't delete them, then the destructor is delete the Octree :

```
Octree::~Octree()
{
clear(root);
}

void Octree::clear(node *node){
for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++)
    if (node->child[i])
        clear(node->child[i]);

delete node;
}
```

But when I'd like to delete a concrete node with this method,

```
void Octree::deletebranch(int branch) {
node *n = search(branch);
if (n) {
    for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
        if (n->child[i]) {
            delete n->child[i];
            n->child[i] = NULL;
        }
    }
    delete n;
    n = NULL;
}
else {
    printf("There is nothing to delete here");
}
}
```

I got an exception after the destructor called.
  Exception thrown: read access violation.
   node was 0x4.

I was debugging step by step and I found some wierd things. When I create a node I do it this way :

```
        n = new node;
        n->value = xvalue;
        for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++)
            n->child[i] = NULL;
```

And it's okay I set the value and the node's value is xvalue and the children are NULL. But after I deleted that node with deletebranch() method my node has changed like this.

- n   0x00500788 {value=0 child=0x0050078c {0x00000004 {value=??? child=0x00000008 {???, ???, ???, ???, ???, ...} }, ...} }   Octree::node *
      value   0   int
- child   0x0050078c {0x00000004 {value=??? child=0x00000008 {???, ???, ???, ???, ???, ???, ???, ???} }, 0xfdfdfdfd {...}, ...}   Octree::node *[8]
- [0] 0x00000004 {value=??? child=0x00000008 {???, ???, ???, ???, ???, ???, ???, ???} }   Octree::node *
- [1] 0xfdfdfdfd {value=??? child=0xfdfdfe01 {???, ???, ???, ???, ???, ???, ???, ???} }   Octree::node *
- [2] 0xdddddddd {value=??? child=0xdddddde1 {???, ???, ???, ???, ???, ???, ???, ???} }   Octree::node *
- [3] 0x29122f71 {value=??? child=0x29122f75 {???, ???, ???, ???, ???, ???, ???, ???} }   Octree::node *
- [4] 0x0000a9bd {value=??? child=0x0000a9c1 {???, ???, ???, ???, ???, ???, ???, ???} }   Octree::node *
- [5] 0x004d5228 {value=5249384 child=0x004d522c {0x005007a0 {value=5067304 child=0x005007a4 {0x004fe218 {...}, ...} }, ...} }    Octree::node *
- [6] 0x004fe218 {value=5244832 child=0x004fe21c {0x004d00c4 {value=5235224 child=0x004d00c8 {0x00501968 {...}, ...} }, ...} }    Octree::node *
- [7] 0xdddddddd {value=??? child=0xdddddde1 {???, ???, ???, ???, ???, ???, ???, ???} }   Octree::node *
- this    0x0043f818 {root=0x005006b0 {value=0 child=0x005006b4 {0x00000000 , 0x00000000 , 0x00000000 , ...} } }    Octree *

I really don't understand why is that because I have never changed the node after I deleted it.
And I think that's why I got that exception in the destructor. How should I delete a node? Maybe try catch?

Here is the header file:

```
class Octree
{ 
public:
struct node
{
    int value;
    node *child[8];
};

Octree();
~Octree();

void clear(node* node);
int convert(int sorszam);
node* searchandset(int dec, int value);
node *search(int dec);
node* step(node *node, int k);
void Print(node *n)const;
void put(int branch, int value);
void deletebranch(int branch);
node *root;
};
```

Comment: Not clear about: *But after I deleted that node with deletebranch() method my node has changed*. Are you looking at a node after it has been deleted.  If so this is UB.

Comment: I don't know what UB is, but yes, I'm looking every node when the destructor is running and the node which I have deleted has children and value. I have copied the node after it has been deleted above.

Comment: This needs a [mcve]. E.g. what is the type of `child`? What does `node` look like? Etc. etc.

Comment: @T.dog UB is short for [Undefined Behaviour](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/ub). Read also through the external links on that page. UB something that you must be familiar with, if you intend to program in c++.

Comment: Regarding the code that searches for a node and saves it as `n` the subsequent `delete n; n = NULL;` - I hope you realize that last assignment to NULL did nothing to *wherever `n` came from*. I.e. somewhere out there is now sitting a non-NULL-but-dangling pointer sitting in a `child[]` array. When its' containing node destructor fires, it will enumerate `child[]` find that pointer, and invoke `delete` therein. But you already deleted the node, thus your problem, and what you have to fix.

Comment: But why `n = NULL;` did nothing? When I only use `delete n;` without `n = NULL;` I got the same exception. But if I understand you I've got a non-NULL pointer somewhere in a node which I've already deleted and when the destructor try to delete it I got that exception. What I don't understand is if I deleted that node, why is the destructor try to delete it again? And how should I set 'n' to NULL to prevent this non-NULL-but-dangling situation?

Comment: @WhozCraig could you please be a little more concrete?