# Copy constructor and destructor octree c++

Tags: c++, destructor, copy-constructor, octree

I have created an Octree data structure but it's not perfect yet. I'm struggled with the copy constructor and the destructor. 
Here is my header file:

```
class Octree
{
public:
static int lastbranch;
static bool utolsoelotti;

struct node
{
    int value;
    node *child[8];
};

Octree();
~Octree();
Octree(const Octree& oct);

void clear(node* node);
node* searchandset(int dec, int value);
node* search(int dec);
node* step(node *node, int k);
node* copy(node *n);
void Print(node *n)const;
void deletebranch(int branch);
node *root;
};
```

Constructor,destructor,copy contrsuctor

```
Octree::Octree()
{
root = new node;
root->value = 0;

for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++)
    root->child[i] = 0;
}
Octree::~Octree()
{
clear(root);
}

Octree::Octree(const Octree& oct) {
root = copy(oct.root);
}

void Octree::clear(node *node){
    for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++)
        if (node->child[i])
            clear(node->child[i]);

    delete node;
}

Octree::node*Octree::copy(node *n) {
node* n2 = new node;
if (n) {
    for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
        n2->child[i] = copy(n->child[i]);
    }
}
return n2;
}
```

And here is how I created objects in the main:

```
int main() {

Octree tree;
Octree tree2(tree);

tree.searchandset(8, 2);
tree2.Print(tree2.search(8));
return 0;
}
```

In the `searchandset` function I'm giving a value for node number 8 at the first tree. After that I'm calling the copy constructor and print the 8th node of the second tree. The value is the same what I gave for the first tree, but when the desctructor called I always got this exception:

Exception thrown: read access violation.
node was 0xDDDDDDDD.

As I know it means that I tried to delete the nodes which I have already deleted. The object 'tree2' is a different object from 'tree' with the same values and nodes isn't it? Then I don't understand that exception above.
I'm new in c++ and I know it's basic stuff, so if somebody would direct me into the right direction I would very appreciate it.

Comment: Shouldn't `copy` return `n2`?

Comment: You are right. But the problem is still exist.

Comment: If you copy a node which has null children, then in the copy what are the contents of the node in the corresponding slot where the null child was in the original?

Comment: Please add indentation and a complete `main` function leading to the problem

Comment: @4386427 I completed the main function.

Comment: @HostileFork  I don'n know. Can you tell me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem lies the in `copy` function. Let's go it through step by step:

```
node* n2 = new node;

if (n) {
    for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++)
        n2->child[i] = copy(n->child[i]);
}
return n2;
```

For an empty `Octree oct`, constructed with the default constructor, and copied to another `Octree`:

1. A new `node` is created, `n2`
2. `n` is the `root` of `oct`, so the condition if `true`
3. `child[i]` of `n2` has a value of a `copy` of the corresponding child, so call `copy` again
4. A new node `n2` is created
5. `n` is `nullptr` (because the children where all `nullptr` in `oct`), so don't execute condition
6. Return `n2`
7. Repeat steps `3` to `6` 8 times
8. Return the root `n2`
9. Assign new pointer (`n2`) to `root` of the copied object

But wait! Did you notice that in step 6, you are `return`ing a new pointer, even though the child is supposed to be `nullptr`!

That's the problem, because then, in `clear`, you will loop through each child. That's still ok, right? But then, you try to access the children, which are uninitialized (they have random value, the condition will evaluate to `true`), so you get a `Read access violation`, because it's not your memory.

So the **solution**? Only allocate memory for `n2` if `n` is not `nullptr`.

Comment: I have edited my code above. Is that what you  tought for? If I'm doing it this way there are no `Read access violation` but the value of the copied tree is not the same as the original one.

Comment: @T.dog yes, because you are not copying the value

Comment: @T.dog Don't update the original code in the question.

Comment: @Rakete1111 Thank you very much it's perfect now!

Comment: @Rakete1111  Would you please look at this question for a minute? Maybe you could help with this.
[link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37252439/how-to-delete-a-node-of-an-octree-c-node-was-0x4)